# Wordpress friendly urls

Tags: asp.net, wordpress

Im an asp.net developer and I was wondering how wordpress friendly url work without passing the id. on the database level is the post title column indexed and searched for each link.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress's friendly URLs are based on a 'slug' in the database, typically the Post Title in snake case (ex: post-title).

For example, the 'slug' in this URL is 'post-title':

```
http://www.domain.com/post-title/
```

WordPress then redirects all URLs to 'index.php' and does a lookup in the database based on the post slug for the URL passed through to the server variable:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Comment: Thanks but for me it boils down to what is been used as the index in the database, using int or using a string. Im considering the performance implication of using string as I believe this what word press does when using permlink. and isnt there risk of duplicate title. Not used to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress basically uses Short urls which we term as Friendly url

Basically its called as Permalink
"Permalinks are the permanent URLs to your individual weblog posts, as well as categories and other lists of weblog postings. A permalink is what another weblogger will use to link to your article (or section), or how you might send a link to your story in an e-mail message. The URL to each post should be permanent, and never change — hence permalink."

Please read  : http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks